# Memory used by definition of symbol (downvalues etc.)

Tags: memory

Suppose we have a symbol  `x` with many `DownValues`. As a MWE take

```
Clear[x];
Do[With[{i = RandomInteger[10^6]}, x[i] = RandomReal[]], {10^4}]
```

(For the purpose of this question it those not really matter how the downvalues were created. For the application I have in mind, the downvalues may have varying complexity.)

Is there an easy way to obtain the total memory used by `x`?

Comment: ByteCount[DownValues[x]] maybe is an answer.

Comment: Depends what are you after at the end, in case of down values which are/share the same expressions there is a mechanism which 'caches' them.  see `ClearAll[t, x]; Echo[t = MemoryInUse[]]; 
x[1] = RandomReal[1, 10^6]; Echo[MemoryInUse[] - t]; 
x[2] = x[1]; Echo[MemoryInUse[] - t];
Echo@ByteCount@x[1];
Echo@ByteCount[x[2]];` so the sum of those down values sizes is not equal to memory taken.